# Uninstalling Ubuntu Touch From ClockWorkMod

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

Hi I have a HP Touchpad running jelly bean 4.1.2 and I just installed Ubuntu Touch through Clockwork Mod 6 and I was wondering if I can remove Ubuntu from Android or ClockWork mod?

Comment: Just re-install Android via ClockworkMod? That should work fine, I imagine.

Comment: I would just flash it with a new ROM, as long as you didn't override the boot loader when you flashed Ubuntu.